# VS Code Keybinding for Line Break

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

I would like to add a key binding for inserting a line break in the editor (`textInputFocus`). Normally the Return key does this (VS Code calls the key `Enter`). Which command in VS Code can I use?

There is `lineBreakInsert` but this does not behave exactly the same as `Enter` normally does - it inserts a line break but keeps the cursor in the same position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+o",
  "command": "type",
  "args": {
    "text": "\n"
  },
  "when": "textInputFocus"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is my workaround, but it's not a perfect solution:

I installed [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) and added this binding (in `keybindings.json`):

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+o",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
      "lineBreakInsert",
      "cursorDown",
      "cursorHome"
    ]
  },
  "when": "textInputFocus"
}
```

Comment: why don't you mention `"when": "textInputFocus"` in the question

Comment: which command is bound to `Return` key, you can use key bind debugging

Comment: There is no command for a new line or it's hidden, it doesn't show up on that list

Comment: VS Code calls it the `Enter` key so I edited the question, but still, I recorded the key and there is nothing about inserting a new line